# Doctrine 2 Optimizing vote entities

Tags: php, database, doctrine, doctrine-orm, sum

I'm trying to find the optimal way of implementing up/down votes in relation to multiple parent entities.

Currently I'm using `InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")` for vote, with parent relations in the subclasses. I'm also using: `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` - mainly so that I can do `count()` without loading the full vote entity when counting votes from a parent entity perspective.

My problem is that I don't want to implement a separate UpVote and DownVote entity class for every parent relation, but instead use a value field inside the vote base class. Preferably I would want to run `$qb->expr()->sum()` on the lazyloaded ArrayCollection somehow, similar to `count()`. (Such that sum can be returned as scalar from database directly using parent entity alone, without entitymanager, or having to load every single vote entity to sum - E.G in a view script)

Is this supported? (Or how to accomplish my desired effect?)

Not sure if the above is the best solution to this problem though - alternative best practice examples for votes using Doctrine 2 welcome!

***Edit**: Fixed LAZY -> EXTRA_LAZY

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading will still load all objects when trying to count. Using EXTRA_LAZY will issue a count statement when counting objects instead of loading them all.

Comment: Although very useful comment, it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: Have you considered going through DQL and a repository instead of just using the default behaviors?

Comment: For my particular case, I would have to inject entity manager into my view for that, which I really don't want to